# How to show that a polynomial is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

1. How do I show that a polynomial is irreducibel?
2. How do I show that $x^2+1$ is irreducible over the field $F_p$ where $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$?

My guess for number 1) is that inserting all numbers $x$ from zero to $p-1$ into the formula, the polynomial is irreducible as long as $f(x)$ is never zero. That somehow only works for irreducible polynomials of degree 2 or 3.

No idea how to solve exercise 2)

Comment: 2. Is false: for $p = 17$, $x^2 + 1$ is reducible since $4$ is a root. Maybe you wanted $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$?

Comment: @RichardD.James thank you, I corrected it!

Comment: The congruence  $   x^{2}\equiv -1{\bmod {p}} $ is solvable if and only if $ p\equiv1\bmod4$

Comment: The second question likely has several answers already on MSE: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389963/argument-for-why-a2-1-is-never-divisible-by-a-3-mod-4-integer?rq=1

Comment: The second answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215469/characterization-of-irreducible-polynomials-over-finite-fields?rq=1 answers the first question.